# Set “publish to web” in Google spreadsheet using Drive API (PHP)

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use the Google Drive API to set a Google Sheet into "Publish to Web" mode so that I can embed it on my website.

Using the Drive API in my PHP:-

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

$driveservice = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
/*
$copiedFile = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array('name' => 'Project plan'));
$responseBody=$driveservice->files->copy("1hAjKEox4hhlK4aoCVLuUVfTJbKPhFklG1gG9-HsGH7U", $copiedFile);
$sheet_id=$responseBody->id;
*/
$sheet_id="1tYktONmPaaxGaS5ylNn8nTzPjtdEsuYIDHakhap8Amk";
$revisions=$driveservice->revisions;
$sheetinformation =$revisions->listRevisions("1tYktONmPaaxGaS5ylNn8nTzPjtdEsuYIDHakhap8Amk");
$revisions=$sheetinformation->getRevisions();
$count=count($revisions);
$revision_id=$revisions[$count-1]->id;
$finalrevision=$driveservice->revisions->get($sheet_id,$revision_id);
$finalrevision->publishAuto=true;
$driveservice->revisions->update($sheet_id,$revision_id, $finalrevision);

die();
```

As far as I can tell this conforms to the Drive API specification (I really wish they hadn't removed the code examples for PHP!). However, I am getting the following error returned in the Response body:-

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "fieldNotWritable",
    "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Referring to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533957/google-sheets-api-how-to-publish-to-web-for-embeddable-sheet), can you try removing the finalrevision parameter? Seems the sample used fileId and revisionId only.

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters when getting finalrevision:

```
$finalrevision=$driveservice->revisions->get($sheet_id,$revision_id, array('fields' => 'publishAuto'));
```

Without last parameter, get method will return you whole revision (with all fields, including read only ones).