# Publish Google Sheet document to the web using Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-python-api

My goal is to publish a Google Sheet document to the web and get the link using Google Sheets API.

I managed to publish it using [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348444/5494179) and now it says "published" in File -> Publish to the web tab. However, the link given on this tab is different from the original `file id`, and I don'k know how to get it with API.

Comment: You can't work on a published file. Just share it publicly, that way you can still operate REST APIs on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/### Not fileId ###/pubhtml` retrieved when the spreadsheet is published cannot be directly retrieved. At Drive API v2, there was `publishedLink` in Revision as a field. But I confirmed that it cannot be used now. `publishedLink` was removed by updating Drive API from v2 to v3. This might affect to the situation. But I'm not sure about this.

So how about using the following URL as a workaround? In this case, you can access the published spreadsheet using file ID.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=### fileId ###
```

#### Reference :

- [Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Vasily Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. Your answer is valid, however I actually used example from [this page](https://apievangelist.com/2017/07/11/when-you-publish-a-google-sheet-to-the-web-it-als-becomes-an-api/) that also worked for me: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[sheet_id]/pubhtml`

Comment: @Vasily Thank you for your additional information. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.