# Cant find google spreadsheetid with url that has "/d/e"?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am having issues with the google spreadsheet api v4. I have set up an api key and published my google sheet. My link is below. In all of the other examples people say to just take whats between the "/d/" and "/pubhtml" but I have an extra "/e/" in there and ignoring it does not seem to work with the api, I just get

```html
{
      "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND"
      }
    }
```

This is my url given to me when I publish the google sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQbIIHnevZDCqbBupM18fOwQRGl_Nl8-yDZgriC2uftFqytHvCzmMXODPQB1IDbdQS5IIBAdkLt6m4y/pubhtml?gid=1990136369&single=true

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573319/publish-google-sheet-document-to-the-web-using-google-sheets-api/48574768#48574768

Comment: Maybe, Im not sure how to make my sheet use the new url scheme, the file was created in the last 24 hours, shouldn't it default to the new way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can get a shareable link which works just fine.